# An invisible count when reproducing audios in Android Studio

Tags: android, audio

I'm using several audio files in my app. When you click a button, you can hear one of them. However, after hearing 7 of them, you can't hear anymore. What can I do about it?
There is the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mp1= MediaPlayer.create(Principal.this, R.raw.a);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp1.release();
                mp1= MediaPlayer.create(Principal.this, R.raw.a);
                mp1.start();
            }
        });
```

It's the same for each audio.
Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there any error in your LogCat?

Comment: Nope. I don't get any error, it just stops reproducing after the seventh time.

Comment: Don't create a new instance of `MediaPlayer` each time, reuse the same instance.